# ANDROID Show closest 10 locations on mapview

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I am developing a POI locator app. I am parsing a JSON file with over 1600 locations. How would effiecntly compare this list to the current users location and get the closest 10?

**EDIT**
The app is using no server, as I want to use local JSON files.

Comment: compare distance on the server site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using a for loop and measuring the distance between the location and the users location.

```
distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB); 
if (distance <= 1000 * 10) //finding all within 10km Radius.{
 ADD GEOPOINT HERE 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you can store the 1600 locations in a database(like mongodb) which supports geo spatial queries. you can directly query over the database to determine the closest N no.of locations to the given latitude and longitude of the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to find distance by a birds-view approach you can just query your locations and check distance with formula located [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). But if you are going to take roads (graphs) into accounts, I'm afraid you'll need to use some kind of pathfinding service like [google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/) or roll your own. (As far as I know there is no built-in mechanism in Android.)

Answer (score 0):

We were writing this kind of app as well, and performed some performance tests on MySQL and MongoDB. Because MongoDB is document based and stores its data in json format, location based queries(like closest restaurants to the user) completes and returns incredibly fast. As far as I can remember, it was approximately 10 times faster than MySQL. So, even if your application doesn' t currently use a no-sql database, I strongly suggest you to use MongoDB even just for location calculating part of your project.

Comment: I need a all offline method, to use MongoDB you need a server. The whole app is using no internet data other then pin pointing the user location.